# white space while exporting illustration

Tags: adobe-illustrator, icon, export, transparency, png

ok , so I have made an image , something like an icon , and I select the whole image using group selection tool to export it in Jpeg format .  But when I view  this file , there's always some white space around the icon , to make it look  like a rectangular selection.

Is their any way that I can export ONLY the image/icon , without the extra white background due to artboard ??

I am using adobe illustrator CS6

here is the image   : [image]

Comment: Not sure if I understand: if you want to get rid of the white background, and go with transparency, you need to save as png or svg. Jpg does not do tranparency.

Comment: ok , the white background is due to the artboard . I want only the image/icon. Something like tracing the given shape contained within the green and blue area , and cutting out ONLY that part . The resultant won't be a rectangular selection , it will have the shape of the icon only

Comment: JPG will _not_ let you save with transparent background. You must save as PNG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JPG format does **not** support transparency. If you need a transparent image for the web, you **must** save as PNG or GIF.

Answer (score 4):

When you export the image in illustrator, if you save as a PNG you can set the background to transparent.